# Move to next cell on Enter key in Datagridview Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cell

I have a `DataGridView` in which I move from one cell to another whenever the ENTER key is pressed.

I have managed to find solutions for when the cell is in edit mode and not in edit mode.

The problem I'm facing is when the user is at the last row, while he is editing a cell and then presses ENTER, one event is not firing (`selectionChanged`) and the cell does not leave focus. It just exits from edit mode. This is very strange because it only happens in the last row. All other rows are working as expected.

I am using 2 events in order to move to the next cell on Enter key while the cell is in edit mode.

```
private void dgvTT_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseButtons != 0) return;

        if (_celWasEndEdit != null && dgvTT.CurrentCell != null)
        {
            // if we are currently in the next line of last edit cell
            if (dgvTT.CurrentCell.RowIndex == _celWasEndEdit.RowIndex + 1 &&
                dgvTT.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == _celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex)
            {
                int iColNew;
                int iRowNew = 0;
                if (_celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex >= colMaam.Index)
                {
                    iColNew = colMisparHeshbon.Index;
                    iRowNew = dgvTT.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    iColNew = dgvTT.Columns.GetNextColumn(_celWasEndEdit.OwningColumn, DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed, DataGridViewElementStates.None).Index;  
                    iRowNew = _celWasEndEdit.RowIndex;
                }
                dgvTT.CurrentCell = dgvTT[iColNew, iRowNew];
            }
        }
        _celWasEndEdit = null;
    }

    private void dgvTT_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        _celWasEndEdit = dgvTT[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Typically we use a Tab key for this purpose. Why don't you consider that option? Best regards,

Comment: If I could stay with the Tab key, I wouldn't ask this question. It have to be Enter key.

Comment: Using your code, I changed two things: **1)** `if (_celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex >=  colMaam.Index)` to `if (_celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex >= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)` and **2)** `iColNew = colMisparHeshbon.Index;` to `iColNew = 0;`. *I changed them because I don't 100% know what* `colMaam` *and* `colMisparHeshbon` *are exactly*.  With that, your code worked just fine for me.

Comment: it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (iColumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, iRow + 1];
                else
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[iColumn + 1, iRow];
            }
            } 
            catch { }
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        { 
            if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1].Cells[0];
            }
            else
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
                SendKeys.Send("{left}");
            }

        }
```